# Is "coachable" a word?

Tags: word-usage

I was taking some online self improvement classes, the person (or the coach) says that we should be "coachable", and the first thought that I had was about whether that word is actually usable formally for describing our abilities when applying to a job. I researched on Google and couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: You can "legally" append the suffix "-able" to most words similar to "coach".  (I'm guessing the basic category is transitive verbs, but there are no doubt other practical qualifications.)  And the term is certainly used -- I've heard or read it at least a dozen times (and I don't read the sports section).

Comment: 'You can "legally" append the suffix "-able" to most words similar to "coach".' Does this mean the grammar police will only arrest you 33% of the time? Wordness needs more evidence than reasonably productive patterns of agglutination.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - It means that the grammar police will stop you and give you a warning citation 0.3172% of the time.  Problem is, they only do it when you're late for an appointment.

Answer (score 2):

Coachable has not made it into the OED yet, but it is in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coachable), and GloWbE (the corpus of Global Web-based English) has 70 instances of it.

So, it is not common, but it is used. I would find no problem with it in a job application, except that I would wonder if it were being used as a meaningless buzzword: I would discount it unless examples were given to demonstrate its appropriateness.